# App crashed on device and it showed me this log, can I extract any useful information from this?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

My app crashed once, and it never crashed again. But I'm bothered by the fact that I don't know why it crashed. My guess is it's a memory issue, but how can I be sure. Does this log have any useful information?

[image]

Comment: Nothing from debugging prospective!!!

Comment: This log is the last chance if you want to collect some info about crash and you have not any crash log from an XCode or testing service. Not useful if you find the real issue in your coding.

Comment: That's not a crash report. Go back to the previous screen and look for an entry that starts with the name of your app.